# For plotting two lines in R with ggplot2: In the data frame the each = length() function isn't working and is returning the wrong value

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

I'm getting the error: `Error in data.frame(iter = seq_along(test_error), Error = c(test_error,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 10000, 20000, 3` but test_error should be more than 3 and that each = length(test_error) should be setting all rows to the same length, right?

**Code:** here's the reproducible code and [this is the data set](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BRPfNXLn8QmFQonm33DCkg3DjrqHJzEaXT_R0CpTNWw/edit?usp=sharing) from a google spreadsheet

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RSNNS)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotROC)
library(tidyr)

setwd("**set working directory**")
data <- read.csv("WDBC.csv", header=T)
data <- data[,1:4]
data <- scale(data)  # normalizes the data

numHneurons3 = 3
DecTargets = decodeClassLabels(data[,4])
train.test3 <- splitForTrainingAndTest(data, DecTargets,ratio = 0.50) # split

model3_02 <- mlp(train.test3$inputsTrain, train.test3$targetsTrain,  # build model3
                 size = numHneurons3, learnFuncParams = c(0.02),maxit = 10000, 
                 inputsTest = train.test3$inputsTest, 
                 targetsTest = train.test3$targetsTest)

trainFitTar3_02 <- cbind(fitted.values(model3_02), train.test3$targetsTrain)
predictions = predict(model3_02, train.test3$inputsTest)

#--------------------------------------
#     GGPlots of the Iterative Error:
#--------------------------------------

str(model3_02)

test_error <- model3_02$IterativeTestError
train_error <- model3_02$IterativeFitError

error_df <- data.frame(iter = seq_along(test_error), Error = c(test_error, train_error), type = rep(c("test", "train", each = length(test_error)))) 
ggplot(error_df, aes(iter, Error, color = type, each = length(test_error))) + geom_line()
```

**Here's the error:**

```
> error_df <- data.frame(iter = seq_along(test_error), Error = c(test_error, train_error), type = rep(c("test", "train", each = length(test_error)))) 
Error in data.frame(iter = seq_along(test_error), Error = c(test_error,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 10000, 20000, 3
```

Here's are the first ten lines of the data:

```
> data <- scale(data)  # normalizes the data
> head(data, 10)
       PatientID     radius    texture   perimeter
 [1,] -0.2361973  1.0960995 -2.0715123  1.26881726
 [2,] -0.2361956  1.8282120 -0.3533215  1.68447255
 [3,]  0.4313615  1.5784992  0.4557859  1.56512598
 [4,]  0.4317407 -0.7682333  0.2535091 -0.59216612
 [5,]  0.4318215  1.7487579 -1.1508038  1.77501133
 [6,] -0.2361855 -0.4759559 -0.8346009 -0.38680772
 [7,] -0.2361809  1.1698783  0.1605082  1.13712450
 [8,]  0.4326197 -0.1184126  0.3581350 -0.07280278
 [9,] -0.2361759 -0.3198854  0.5883121 -0.18391855
[10,]  0.4329621 -0.4731182  1.1044669 -0.32919213
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

- the bracket in `rep` is at the wrong place.
- `c(test_error, train_error)` combines both vectors and is hence double the length than `seq_along(test_error)`

Try this to be safe

```
error_df <- data.frame(iter = c(seq_along(test_error),
                                seq_along(train_error)),
                       Error = c(test_error, train_error), 
                       type = c(rep("test", length(test_error)),
                                rep("train", length(train_error))
                                ))
```

Comment: I'm getting the error ```Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Error' not found``` could this be because it's contained within iter?

Comment: what throws the error?

Comment: sorry, i messed up a bracket

Comment: the ggplot ```> ggplot(error_df, aes(iter, Error, color = type, each = length(test_error))) + geom_line()```

Comment: No problem, I appreciate the help! It's not throwing an error anymore but the graph is empty, is there an issue with a parameter?

Comment: it is basically impossible to tell without a minimal reproducible example, i.e. some sample data

Comment: I had a link to a public google spreadsheet of the data but I've edited it to also include a snippet of the first ten lines from the data set